# Hostname for CSS and JS Aggregation

Tags: 8, css-js-aggregation

We would like to place the aggregated CSS and JS onto a CDN as static resources.  To accomplish this we need to load these resources with a special hostname.  Let's say the base url of the website is www.foo.com.  We would like to load the aggregated CSS and JS using static.foo.com.  All assets associated with static.foo.com will be placed onto the CDN.

What is the best way to associate a unique hostname with aggregated CSS and JS?  The goal is to have href="//static.foo.com/.. in the resulting html.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/cdn

Comment: I am aware of the cdn module and have used it in the past.  We would like to keep this site very simple.  We are just looking to change a few hostnames.  Thanks